# Fire only the currently equipped weapon, not all weapons

Tags: unity, c#

I have two guns and two different functions for it.

I pick up the weapon by making weapon a child of the parent player.

When the player presses the "Fire1" button, I want only the current weapon the player has picked up to shoot.

Unfortunately, with the code below, both weapons shoot, even the one that was not picked up.

How can I correct this?

```
public class weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firepoint1; //this is a firepoint
    public Transform firepoint2; //this is a firepoint

    public GameObject bulletprefab;
    public GameObject f;
    public GameObject f1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
    }

    void shoot()
    {   
         Instantiate(bulletprefab, firepoint1.position, firepoint1.rotation);
    }

    void shoot1()
    {        
         Instantiate(bulletprefab, firepoint2.position, firepoint2.rotation);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D trig)
    {
        if (f.gameObject != null && gameObject.tag =="player")
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                shoot();
            }      
        }
        if (f.gameObject != null && gameObject.tag == "player")
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                shoot1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would substantially refactor this code. A weapon's job is to shoot *when it is commanded to shoot*. Knowing which weapon is equipped, and interpreting player inputs into commands is not the job of the weapon, but of a player inventory & character control script.

That could look something like this `WeaponHandler` script you can attach to your player character object, to handle picking up & firing weapons:

```
public class WeaponHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform weaponSlot;
    public string fireButtonName = "Fire1";

    Weapon _currentWeapon;

    // We listen for input in just one place,
    // and send a command to the weapon script when we want it to shoot.
    // This shoots the single instance we have equipped, not all weapons.
    public void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown(fireButtonName) && _currentWeapon != null) {
            _currentWeapon.Shoot();
        }
    }    

    // Since you haven't shown us your weapon pick-up code,
    // I'm going to make some simple guesses here.
    // Replace this with the weapon pick-up method you like.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trigger) {
        if (trigger.TryGetComponent(out Weapon collidedWeapon)) {
            PickUpWeapon(collidedWeapon);
        }    
    }

    public void PickUpWeapon(Weapon newWeapon) {
        // Throw away our old weapon, if we had one.
        if (_currentWeapon != null) {
            Destroy(_currentWeapon.gameObject);
        }

        // Attach the new weapon to our carrying slot,
        // and snap it to a standardized position/orientation.
        newWeapon.transform.parent = weaponSlot;
        newWeapon.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        newWeapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        
        // Record this as our weapon to fire from now on.
        _currentWeapon = newWeapon;
    }
}
```

Then the `Weapon` class can be simpler, and just fire when it's told:

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    // End of the weapon muzzle(s), where bullets should spawn.
    public Transform[] firePoints;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public void Shoot()
    {   
         // Spawn a bullet at the end of each muzzle.
         // (Here we assume the bullet script applies its own velocity).
         foreach (var firePoint in firePoints) {
             Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
         }
    }
}
```

You can now configure two separate weapons (or more!) with different bullets and fire points, and the `WeaponHandler` on the player will equip and fire just one at a time.

This structure also helps set you up for...

- Local Multiplayer: each player can have their own `WeaponHandler` that listens to just their own input.
- New Input System: this centralizes your input-listening in one place (the player character), making it easier to switch to the New Input System package, which handles input maps as swappable assets rather than a single global map.
- AI Weapon Users: this allows non-player characters to also use weapons by calling their `Shoot()` method, without needing a separate class of AI-only weapons.